# push new list item not to the bottom instead to the top.

Tags: javascript

I would like to push a new element in the list always on top instead on the bottom. How can i do this?

This is my Code:

```
function saveToList(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        var movieName = document.getElementById('movieName').value.trim();
        if (movieName.length > 0) {
            var li = '<div>' + movieName + '</div>';
            document.getElementById('favMovies').innerHTML += li;
        }
        document.getElementById('movieName').value = '';
        return false;
    }
}
```

[...]

```
function refreshUI(list) {
    var lis = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        lis += '<div data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].name + '<div>';
    };
    document.getElementById('favMovies').innerHTML = lis;
};
```

Comment: Read about unshift();     function in javascript  ... That will sovle your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can in do this way.

```
function refreshUI(list) {
    var lis = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        lis.push('<div data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].name + '<div>');
    };
    document.getElementById('favMovies').innerHTML = lis.reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: Yes! That worked in combination with firebase. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So for the first one, you add the li before the innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById('favMovies').innerHTML = li + document.getElementById('favMovies').innerHTML;
```

Second one you loop backwards over the array.

```
for (var i = list.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
```